# DataTables with Bootstrap and ColVis

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

jQuery DataTables with the Bootstrap design, seems to working fine, no issues.
But when I try to use ColVis with it, it breaks everything.

I tried the minimal CSS, different JavaScript files from ColVis which didn't fixed it. Weird.

However, that's my CSS/Javascript with screenshots I was using:

http://pastebin.com/F83sthP7

Any suggestion how to fix it?

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/colvis/1.1.0/css/dataTables.colVis.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColVis/js/dataTables.colVis.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
      dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip'
   } );
} );
</script>
```

**Screenshots:**

---

[image: Screenshot 1]]

---

[image: Screenshot 2]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Bootstrap add-on for jQuery DataTables requires  [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option other than default `'lfrtip'`. Unfortunately this is not documented anywhere but can be discovered by inspecting [add-on source code](//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js).

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) necessary for Twitter Bootstrap style (as seen in add-on source code) and modified so that ColVis button appears correctly.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      dom:
        "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-3'f><'col-sm-3 text-right'C>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
        "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",        
   });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
div.ColVis, button.ColVis_Button {
  float:none;
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8r0me2r/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @Neoon, corrected code for better appearance on smaller screens.